How to pass different principals when deploying a bucket policy using terraform
Using terraform I am creating a simple bucket and applying a simple bucket policy that allows a role and a user to get access to it. The role/user is different for each account that is being deployed.
# Creating buckets
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "buckets" {
  for_each = var.s3_bucket_names
    
  bucket = "${var.prefix}-${var.environment}-${lower(var.github_branch)}-${each.key}"
}
    
# Apply Bucket policy to buckets.
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "allow_access_to_bucket" {
  for_each = aws_s3_bucket.buckets
    
  bucket = each.value.id
  policy = templatefile("s3_policy.json", {
    tmp_s3_arn  = "${each.value.arn}",
    object_access = "${var.s3_object_access}"
  })
}

Then the policy is like:
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "S3ObjectPermissions",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::${tmp_account}:role/role_case_one",
                        "arn:aws:sts::${tmp_account}:assumed-role/dev_role/user@here.com"]
                },
                "Action": [
                    "s3:GetObject",
                    "s3:PutObject",
                    "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                    "s3:DeleteObject"
                ],
                "Resource": "${tmp_s3_arn}/*"
            }
        ]
    }

But I want to parametrize the principal as they may change on different accounts. I have tried to replace the list of principals for a list in terraform, but it is trying to "add" a new terraform with the information of the list.
I tried to pass just a string and the same, it tries to add the string ad additional principal.
    ~ Principal = {
     ~ AWS = [
       - "arn:aws:iam::12345:role/role_case_one",
       - "arn:aws:sts::12345:assumed-role/assumed-role/dev_role/user@here.com",
     ] -> "[arn:aws:iam::12345:role/role_case_one,arn:aws:iam::12345:assumed-role/assumed-role/dev_role/user@here.com]"

How can I achieve this?

How did you try to add a list? Can you add that to the question as well? Also, you don't show the example when using object_access, rather you show the tmp_account and tmp_s3_arn.

Why are you adding the IAM principal ARNs to the S3 bucket policy? Typically you would add permissions to the IAM principal's IAM policies?

@MarkoE -- My tfvars had the list 'object_access' as [principalare1, principalarn2, etc.] I tried by replacing the list on the policy with the variable as well as by passing it -- none of them work, all were adding a string with all the principals (instead on the list)

@jarmod -- This bucket has sensitive data, so adding a policy to allow only a couple of roles to access it, no one else, not even if their policies allow it.

@JuanLuna your bucket policy does not actually achieve that. Any IAM principal that has S3 permissions for this bucket will be able to access it. Your bucket policy, as written, simply allows certain additional access. It doesn't prevent others who have permission through their IAM policies. To do that your bucket policy would need to deny those other principals (specifically it would need to deny NOT role/role_case_one and NOT assumed-role/dev_role/user@here.com).

@jarmod, apologies for my delay in the response. You are absolutely right and thank you for bringing that up. I made the necessary changes to make it as secure as needed.

I think what you want is to use the built-in jsonencode function within the templated file. For example, something like this should work:
# Creating buckets
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "buckets" {
  for_each = var.s3_bucket_names
    
  bucket = "${var.prefix}-${var.environment}-${lower(var.github_branch)}-${each.key}"
}
    
# Apply Bucket policy to buckets.
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "allow_access_to_bucket" {
  for_each = aws_s3_bucket.buckets
    
  bucket = each.value.id
  policy = templatefile("s3_policy.json", {
    tmp_s3_arn    = each.value.arn
    roles         = ["arn:aws:iam::12345:role/role_case_one", "arn:aws:sts::12345:assumed-role/assumed-role/dev_role/user@here.com"]
  })
}

The templated file should then look like the following:
${jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3ObjectPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [ for role in roles:
                   role
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "${tmp_s3_arn}/*"
        }
    ]
})}

You can also check more examples in the documentation. This works:
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_s3_bucket.buckets["averyimportantbucketmarkoe"] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket" "buckets" {
      + acceleration_status         = (known after apply)
      + acl                         = (known after apply)
      + arn                         = (known after apply)
      + bucket                      = "averyimportantbucketmarkoe"
      + bucket_domain_name          = (known after apply)
      + bucket_prefix               = (known after apply)
      + bucket_regional_domain_name = (known after apply)
      + force_destroy               = false
      + hosted_zone_id              = (known after apply)
      + id                          = (known after apply)
      + object_lock_enabled         = (known after apply)
      + policy                      = (known after apply)
      + region                      = (known after apply)
      + request_payer               = (known after apply)
      + tags_all                    = (known after apply)
      + website_domain              = (known after apply)
      + website_endpoint            = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_s3_bucket_policy.allow_access_to_bucket["averyimportantbucketmarkoe"] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "allow_access_to_bucket" {
      + bucket = (known after apply)
      + id     = (known after apply)
      + policy = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_s3_bucket.buckets["averyimportantbucketmarkoe"]: Creating...
aws_s3_bucket.buckets["averyimportantbucketmarkoe"]: Creation complete after 1s [id=averyimportantbucketmarkoe]
aws_s3_bucket_policy.allow_access_to_bucket["averyimportantbucketmarkoe"]: Creating...
aws_s3_bucket_policy.allow_access_to_bucket["averyimportantbucketmarkoe"]: Creation complete after 1s [id=averyimportantbucketmarkoe]

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.


Hello @MarkoE -- This is exactly what I was looking, thank you very much for your response and example! I was missing the part of "for role in roles: role" reason why it was using the entire list as a string. Thanks again!
